# Warning: require() [function.require]: open_basedir restriction in effect is not within the allowed path(s)

Tags: javascript, php, html, asp.net, windows

I have a broken file here and it's  writing that code error. The error message comes from:

```
Warning: require() [function.require]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(C:/Websites/contact/contact-files/contact-form-run.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (D:/InetPub/vhosts/carservicecity.net\;C:\Windows\Temp\) in D:\InetPub\vhosts\carservicecity.net\httpdocs\book\form.php on line 13
```

This has killed website completely.  Here's the website here [Click here to view website](http://carservicecity.net/book/default.asp)

What files should I look into and what to correct? Please help me this a client website. I took over the website from another website designer.

Answer (score 0):

Look in `D:\InetPub\vhosts\carservicecity.net\httpdocs\book\form.php` on line 13. There should be an absolute path which you have to change.

Line 13 wants to access `C:/Websites/contact/contact-files/contact-form-run.php` but PHP let's you only access files in and under `D:/InetPub/vhosts/carservicecity.net\` and `C:\Windows\Temp\`

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at that and will respond to you back

Comment: 'if ( !file_put_contents($file, $string, LOCK_EX) ){
       return false;'  **what does this code mean** it's seems to denying access?

Comment: What? Is this line 13? Then search where $file is set. That should be the path to the file.

Comment: That codes from the contact-form.php. Line 13 of the form.php is this:   **require $contact_form_path . 'contact-form-run.php';**

Comment: So it looks like you have to change $contact_form_path into the path, where your contact-form-run.php takes place now.

Comment: This seems to be the path: **Carservicecity.net\httpdocs\book\form.php** I just don't understand how the **C://websites, D://inetpub and C://windows** directories work? The website is windows hosted and runs on asp.net and php langauge...I'm accessing it via FTP throght httpdocs folder...

Comment: Well, in PHP you can set open_basedirs in the config, because then PHP Scripts cannot read or write files to directory's they doesn't should have access to. What you have to do is to find the 'contact-form-run.php' in your httpdocs folder and change the path from $contact_form_path to this. For me it looks like you have to set $contact_form_path to '../../book/'...but I'm not sure

Comment: Okay, I will change the form.php to read the path of contact-form.php as well as contact-form.php for form.php....*fingerscrossed*

Comment: one error from those 4 errors is gone...Let me continue with it..I hope it doesn't ask for windows authentication asking for username and password because it did that in the past

Comment: Which 4? Is the error of this thread solved? Then accept answer please, so that other users can see that this solution worked.

Comment: With the changes through...it now says **
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in D:\InetPub\vhosts\carservicecity.net\httpdocs\book\form.php on line 13**  The code looks like this **<?php
$contact_form = 1; // set desired form number.
$contact_form_path = 'D:\InetPub\vhosts\carservicecity.net\httpdocs\contact\contact-files\'; // set path to /contact-files/ with slash on end.
require $contact_form_path . 'contact-form-run.php';
?>**

Comment: It's hard to read in the comment, but unexpected T_STRING is often caused by a missing ; in the line before.